# Is there any language which is close to C/C++ yet easy to automatically parallize?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, fortran

This is from [the Wikipedia article on Automatic parallelization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization)

> Automatic parallelization by compilers or tools is very difficult due to the 
>   following reasons[2]:
>
> 1. dependence analysis is hard for code using indirect addressing, pointers, 
>      recursion, and indirect function calls;
> 2. loops have an unknown number of iterations;
> 3. accesses to global resources are difficult to coordinate in terms 
>      of memory allocation, I/O, and shared variables.

As you can see, the problem with the 1st point has mostly to do with programming language. In C/C++ you have all the problems mentioned in point 1. So my question is, do we have a language which is close to C/C++ but without these problems. I know Fortran fills the bill, but it is not even remotely like C/C++.

Comment: Let's back up: are there any languages which allow for easy automatic parallelization?  If not, then you have your answer.  If so, then you have a (probably very small) list of languages to look over.

Comment: The best parallelization tool is the human brain, with a litte effort and a so called thread pool, any language will do.

Comment: There are various source code transformation tools which more or less produce MPI and/or OpenMP enabled source. There also exists this automatic parallelisation of _safe_ loops supported by most C/C++ and Fortran compilers (restricted to producing multithreaded code only - no MPI). And last but not least there are novel concepts in expressing algorithms (in C++) that automatically generate parallel code appropriate for the specific hardware platform (using MPI/OpenMP/CUDA/OpenCL) - see [FLAME](http://z.cs.utexas.edu/wiki/flame.wiki/) for concrete example.

Comment: @demorge - lets back up further - it may have escaped your attention that the females of our species are better at multitasking. It is a tricky subject.

Comment: Fortran is actually very close to C/C++. There can be even automatic converters sometimes generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FORTRAN has a few unique features (probably best described as lack of features) which allow for clean, automatic parallelization; however, with all of the recent additions to FORTRAN, it isn't clear if the modern equivalents of the language maintain such a distinction.

As far as comparison to C and C++, FORTRAN is not too far off the beaten path in terms of logic structures; however, to do sophisticated data structures, FORTRAN's roots tended to store a structure across several associated arrays, and then use particular fields as the "next" index.  This avoided pointers, but offered similar flexibility.

I've seen FORTRAN implementations of hash tables, trees and other structures back when I worked with the language more; but, it definately wasn't written to easily represent such, and I'd imagine that such code is hard to parallelize.

Answer (score 3):

There are several standards that introduce syntax for parallelization in C and C++.
One example is [Unified Parallel C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Parallel_C), another is [openCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), through both have vastly different purposes.

The one that probably best fits your bill is [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). It extends the C and C++ language so you can tell the compiler to parallelize your code (and where to do it).

Functional programming languages (e.g. Lisp, Haskell and F#) are by their very nature highly and automatically parallelizable, but are also vastly different from procedural and OOP languages like C and C++

Comment: I think it is OpenMP what you were looking for (well, for C++, I dont know if C has it).

Comment: OpenMP is indeed the one I was thinking of, it for both C and C++ :). I found it just when you posted your comment.

Comment: OpenMP is nowhere near automatic.

Comment: I would not classify UPC as automatically parallelising language given its explicit parallel constructs and special memory model. Yet it is more easy to understand than MPI code.

Comment: Removed automatic as indeed none of those standards are close to automatic, but they probably do represent the best you can get with C/C++. Also added a paragraph about functional programming languages as they are truly automatically parallelizable.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for parallelization on a GPU

there is Microsoft's [AMP](http://techreport.com/discussions.x/21134)

The PGI compiler and in the future more compilers will support the openmp like [Open ACC](http://www.openacc-standard.org/%20%22Open%20ACC)

Caps has also released another openMP like compiler called [HMPP](http://www.caps-entreprise.com/hmpp.html)

Comment: its on the PGI compiler, and will be in future gcc releases as for the others i am unsure

Comment: and HMPP , still more advanced then openAcc

Comment: @VladimirF ah true I forgot about HMPP i thought they were merging it with openACC? I could be mistaken

Comment: CAPS will support both, but they are different. HMPP has still more features.

Comment: theres also Microsoft AMP let me revise this